# Did not send the Url request to the server in iPhone

Tags: iphone, character-encoding, nsurlrequest

I have faced the problem at first time when i send the url request it didn't complete.

My Url is:
https://www.company name.com/apps/webservice/index.php?op=Newtips&campaign_id=38&title=löp&touserid=4&description=Ålägg

when i send without swedish character it works fine but when i send request with this character it didn't give me response.

Please help me to solved this problem
Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method of `NSString`, before initializing `NSURL` with it.

UPDATE:

for example:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://www.company name.com/apps/webservice/index.php?op=Newtips&campaign_id=38&title=löp&touserid=4&description=Ålägg";
NSString *encodedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];
```

Comment: it's contain swedish, danish, finnish, Norwegian language. so i have to replace all special characters?

Comment: you just once use this method for the whole URL string; it will replace special characters, if any will be found; if no special symbols will be found - no replacement will be done; i've updated my answer with a small example